# Eclipse Unable To Run ScrapBook VM

Tags: java, eclipse

I am just starting to code with eclipse and i cannot use the scrapbook.
i am on Mac Mini, osx mavericks, jdk1.7u51.

Error:

Exception occurred executing command line.

Cannot run program "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Home/bin/java":error=2, no such file or directory.

I looked in the directory stated and the file "java" is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my java work space was under a chinese directory.